# Laravel 5.2 Pivot table data update issue

Tags: php, json, laravel, many-to-many

I have a cart table and items table, with a many to many relationship between them. The pivot table contains additional columns - 'Quantity' and 'line_price'.

The method in my controller is to update the quantity and refresh the line_price.

My cart controller method:

```
protected function UpdateQuantity($cartid, $itemid, $quantity)
{
    $cart = Cart::where('id', $cartid)->first();
    $item = $cart->items()->where('item_id', $itemid)->first();

    $item->pivot->quantity = $quantity;
    $item->pivot->save();

    $cart->refresh();

    return Response::json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Item quantity updated in cart',
        'lineprice' => $item->pivot->line_price,
    ]);
}
```

and the method on my Cart model:

```
public function refresh()
{

    foreach ($this->items as $item){
        $item->pivot->line_price = $item->pivot->quantity * $item->price;
        $item->pivot->save();
    }
    $this->save();

}
```

The database updates correctly when i call this method but, the JSON response 'lineprice' does not update unless the method is called twice.

The logic on refresh() method seems to be correct, but i'm unable to fetch the updated value of lineprice in my JSON response after refresh()

How can i fix this?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `$item` variable is not refreshed with the new line_price. 
A hack would be to reload it the same way it's loaded.

```
$item = $cart->items()->where('item_id', $itemid)->first();
```